# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.' Any Advice?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-core

This is my first post and this problem is really persisting, I am having this issue with my code where it breaks when I try to click my "Post Review" button.

```
public partial class add_review : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void btnSub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String myConStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDBCon"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(myConStr))
        {
            string mySQL = "INSERT INTO Reviews (rTitle, rDate";

            mySQL += "rAuthor, rStar, rFull,) ";
            mySQL += "VALUES (@rTitle, @rDate, @rAuthor, rStar ";
            mySQL += "  @rFull, GETDATE())  ";

            using (SqlCommand myCom = new SqlCommand(mySQL,myCon))
            {
                myCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rTitle", txtTitle.Text);
                myCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rDate", txtDate.Text);
                myCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rAuthor", txtAuthor.Text);
                myCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rStar", txtStar.Text);
                myCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rFull", txtFull.Text);

                myCon.Open();
                myCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        pnlForm.Visible = false;
        pnlThanks.Visible = true;
        String myOut = "<p>Thank you for your submission; remember to double check your grammar!</p>";
        myOut += "<h2>" + txtTitle.Text + "</h2>";
        myOut += "<span class='rDate'>" + txtDate.Text + "</span> by <strong>";
        myOut += txtAuthor.Text + "</strong><br/>";
        myOut += txtFull.Text + "</div>";

        lblOut.Text = myOut;
    }
}
```

I have tried to pinpoint exactly what it was but I just could not find anything, I am wondering if there is something simple I am looking over? Thank you so much.

Comment: I have updated my code, thank you so much for all of you that helped, it was a mixture of me having in GETDATE() , missing the @rStar , and I also compressed the INSERT statement into:
```
string mySQL = "INSERT INTO Reviews (rTitle, rDate, rAuthor, rStar, rFull) ";
mySQL += "VALUES (@rTitle, @rDate, @rAuthor, rStar, @rFull) ";
```

Comment: string mySQL = "INSERT INTO Reviews (rTitle, rDate, rAuthor, rStar, rFull) ";
            mySQL += "VALUES (@ rTitle, @ rDate, @ rAuthor, @ rStar, @ rFull) ";
            using (SqlCommand myCom = new SqlCommand(mySQL,myCon))


--------------

This was the end product that ended up working

Comment: https://prnt.sc/113ejax

Here is a link to a visual of what worked

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string mySQL = "INSERT INTO Reviews (rTitle, rDate";
mySQL += "rAuthor, rStar, rFull,) ";
mySQL += "VALUES (@rTitle, @rDate, @rAuthor, rStar ";
mySQL += "  @rFull, GETDATE())  ";
```

Try

```
string mySQL = "INSERT INTO Reviews (rTitle, rDate, rAuthor, rStar, rFull) ";
mySQL += "VALUES (@rTitle, @rDate, @rAuthor, @rStar, @rFull) ";
```

Comment: Thank you for that but I still get an error and it highlights myCom.ExecuteNonQuery(); https://prnt.sc/113e6b8

Comment: are you passing 6 values to 5 fields ?   and rStar should be @rStar in values?

Comment: Looks like there are multiple issues, have edited above. You either have `getdate()` by mistake or are missing a column from your insert list.

Answer (score 0):

Good day,
I’ve noticed that you declare the command string like this:

```
string mySQL = "INSERT INTO Reviews (rTitle, rDate";
```

You need to put a `,` after the `rDate` Or before the completion of the string just before `rAuthor` .
So either you change the declaration line to `string mySQL = "INSERT INTO Reviews (rTitle, rDate,";` 
Or the completion of the statement line to

```
mySQL += ", rAuthor, rStar, rFull,) ";
```

Also you need to change this line

```
mySQL += "VALUES (@rTitle, @rDate, @rAuthor, rStar ";
```

To

```
mySQL += "VALUES (@rTitle, @rDate, @rAuthor, @rStar, ";
```

Comment: Thank you but this still did not work,  https://prnt.sc/113e9w2

Comment: And please let me know if the update solved the issue

Comment: It did, a combination of these answers helped, thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0):

Embed static SQL in C# like this:

```
            string mySQL = @"
INSERT INTO Reviews (rTitle,  rDate,  rAuthor,  rStar,  rFull) 
             VALUES (@rTitle, @rDate, @rAuthor, @rStar, @rFull);
";
```